# How to do a sumif partial text matches on two ranges of data in Excel on different workbooks

Tags: excel, excel-formula

As it says I'm trying to match the first range of strings to see if a part of the string is included in the second range of strings.

Example:

> Range 1 pl, on, bd, ac
>
> Range 2 apple, orange, monkey, actor

I would imagine the result to be 3, becase pl is in apple, on is in monkey, and ac is in actor.

My current *incorrect* formula is:

```
=COUNTIFS('December 2013 Data'!$A$2:$A$1721,"*"&'Heart-related Condition Codes'!B2:B17&"*")
```

It is returning "0" and not counting any of the data.

One sheet is called 'December 2013 Data,' and one is called 'Heart-related Condition Codes'

Edit:

Example December Data:
[image: December Data could be]
Example Condition Codes:

[image: Condition Codes Here]
Each of the December data entries has VVN284 so the result of the equation should be 6.

Answer (score 0):

If your data on the **December 2013 Data** sheet has the same structure across board which is

> L893 (**4** characters prefix) + XXX (**random number** of characters) + Condition Code (**6**
>   characters) + TGU3 (**4** characters suffix)

Then you can use an array formula with the combination of **SUM**, **COUNTIF** and **MID** functions to find the desired result.

Please note I have defined the following **names** in my example:

1) Data range on the **December 2013 Data** sheet is named as **Data_2013Dec**

2) Condition code on the **Heart-related Condition Codes** sheet is named as **Condition_Code**

Here is the formula:

```
{=SUM(COUNTIF(Condition_Code,(MID(Data_2013Dec,(LEN(Data_2013Dec)-10+1),6))))}
```

Please note it is an array formula so you need to press **CSE** `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` upon finishing the formula to make it work.

See below picture for clarifications.

[image: Answer]

Once again, my solution will only work with the condition that the original data always have 4-Character prefix, 4-Character suffix, and 6-Character condition code. Or if your actual data has a different structure but still consistent across board, you may be able to work out your own MID function to find the condition code within the data range and then do a SUM and COUNTIF to find the total number.